# Download from Share folder

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I have installed Ubuntu recently and I need to download some files from my office share folder. but I cant access to the share folder. I tried several YouTube videos options and so many websites. but most of them are showing how to share a folder. but I wanted to know how to access to a share folder which is already created in a another server. **can anyone help me to solve this problem?** because all the file works in my office is done through share folder

**I have installed Ubuntu 19.04** *Shared folder is located in windows server. the path is like a IP address like //3X.6X.11.51/'New Share'/093-Jayasanka*

Comment: We'll need more information to solve this.  Including but not limited to **examples** of what you've tried, what paths are needed to access the shared folders, etc. whether the shares are Windows/Samba shares, etc.

Comment: Shared folder is located in windows server. the path is like a IP address like //30.60.11.51/'New Share'/093-Jayasanka

Comment: @BasuruJayasanka What have you tried? Have you tried entering \\30.60.11.51\ into the file manager for instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone got same problem, This is what I found! 
 to use this code it is required to know the Windows PC username and the Password.

```
sudo mount.cifs -o username=(username of the windows PC) //(IP address of Windows PC)/(Path of the windows share folder) /(path of your share folder)
```

and if you need to unmount use this

```
sudo umount -a -t cifs
```

I have fined this answer after watching about 30 videos. so I'm posting this for help anyone face same as me... good luck.